# Hiding login form when logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form in my nav bar which includes a username and password textbox as well as a sign in button. When the user logs in I am trying to understand how I would hide the login form and show a profile button, I am wondering how may I come across doing it in ASP.NET? I am using Bootstrap, I know how to log the user in but I don't know how I would change it to show a profile button when the user is logged in.

Here is what I have so far in my MasterPage.Master source code:

```
<body role="document">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 1px;">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
      </form>
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I know the answer will be way longer than this but I'll try to set you on a path. Basically on ASP.NET you have views which you'll send according to some server logic. In your case, you'll have a login view, and then after used is correctly logged in, you'll send a welcome/firstPage view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web Forms way of doing this is to use a [`LoginView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control.

```
<asp:LoginView id="LoginView1" runat="server">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        <!-- this is displayed if no user is logged in -->
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        <!-- this is displayed once logged in. may wanna leave it empty -->
     </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```